# Any way for a combo box with two separate columns?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm looking for an option with which I can view large amount of options in combobox in parallel way !!! 
sorry for my bad english , but i use photo shop to explain my idea .

[image]

again the above pic was done by photoshop not with vb :)

I use this code two display items in combobox and centralize header items

```
    Private Sub ComboBox3_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.DrawItem

    If Not e.Index < 0 Then

        e.DrawBackground()
        Dim text As String = CType(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString()

        If text.StartsWith("=") Then

            Dim f As New Font(CType(sender, ComboBox).Font, FontStyle.Bold)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds, Color.Maroon)

        Else

            Dim f As New Font(CType(sender, ComboBox).Font, FontStyle.Regular)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, New Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y), Color.Black)

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

the above code worked fine but i can't draw items in multiple columns .

so, any help ???? thanks in advance :)

sorry for my bad English again

Comment: Your closest option most likely is a ListView with groups.

Comment: thanks, i'll try searching this

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx should give you a start.

Comment: thanks, but any way to make multiple columns ???

Comment: Your DrawItem event handler is going to need multiple DrawText() calls.  One for each column.  This still isn't going to work very well, the user can't pick an item from a column, only a row.  You can buy this kind of control from component vendors.

Comment: If you switch the project to wpf there is a way to do it.  The [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/vstudio?query=multi%20column%20combobox&Refinement=195&ac=2#refinementChanges=&pageNumber=1&showMore=false) have several examples.

Comment: `WPF` is the way to go!

Comment: OK, any example with WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a TreeView?

Setup Foods/Drinks/Extras/Items/Others as a Parent Node with their items as Child Nodes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx